# Get all elements in a Python list starting from an index

Tags: python, list, indexing

Say I have a list arr and an index i within [0:len(arr)], how do I get all the elements starting from arr[i] up to arr[-1] in a Pythonic way?
For example:

```
arr = 'abcdef' 
i = 3
```

I basically want to get b = 'def'
I tried

```
b = a[i:-1]
```

but obviously that'll leave out the last element. 
Also, my list sometimes has only 1 element, so i = 0. How do I safely treat that edge case?
Thank you!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1965736 - what you are looking for is called slicing

Comment: You are looking for slicing, existing questions cover the topic. Try this one: [understading python list slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 3):

You could use python list slicing like this:

```
b = arr[i:]    # This prints 'def' when arr = 'abcdef' and i = 3
```

This will print everything from the `i`th position to the end. And if `i` is greater than the string length, it'll print an empty string.